# Giving a state to parent component in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I know you can pass down states and props in React from a parent component to a child component, but is there any way to do this the opposite way?

For example:

Given some child component:

```
var Child = React.createClass({

  getInitialState: function(){
    return {
      data: ''
    };
  },

  componentDidMount: function(){
    this.setState({data: 'something'});
  },

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

and given some parent component:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({

  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child />
        ...
      </div>
    );
  }

});
```

Is there any way for me to give `Parent` the value of the state data from `Child`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No.

But yes. But really no.

You cannot "pass" anything from a child to a parent in React. However, there are two solutions you can use to simulate such a passing.

1) pass a callback from the parent to the child

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  getInitialState: function() {
    return {
      names: []
    };
  },
  addName: function(name) {
    this.setState({
      names: this.state.names.push(name)
    });
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      <Child 
        addName={this.addName}
      />
    );
  }
});

var Child = React.createClass({
  props: {
    addName: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  handleAddName: function(event) {
    // This is a mock
    event.preventDefault();
    var name = event.target.value;
    this.props.addName(name);
  },
  render: function() {
    return (
      ...
        onClick={this.handleAddName}
      ...
    );
  }
});
```

The second option is to have a top-level state by using a [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/)-style action/store system, such as [Reflux](https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs) or [Redux](https://github.com/reactjs/redux). These basically do the same thing as the above, but are more abstract and make doing so on much larger applications very easy.

Comment: Thank you very much - I was able to use your approach to solve my issue.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do this is through a 'render props' pattern I was recently introduced to. Remember, `this.props.children` is really just a way for React to pass things down to a component.

For your example:

```
var Parent = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
    return (
      <div>
        <Child>
          {(childState) => {
             // render other 'grandchildren' here
          }}
        </Child>
      </div>
    );
  }
});
```

And then in `<Child>` render method:

```
var Child = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    children: React.PropTypes.func.isRequired
  },
  // etc
  render () {
    return this.props.children(this.state);
  }
});
```

This is probably best suited for cases where the `<Child />` is responsible for doing something but doesn't really care much at all about the children that would be rendered in its place. The example the react training guys used was for a component that would fetch from Github APIs, but allow the parent to really control what / if anything was rendered with those results.